# Azure Autoscaling with pre-built servers (Availability Sets)?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, autoscaling, azure-availability-set

Our scenario, we currently have bamboo set up with remote agents on each of them. We want to go to azure, where we can automatically ramp up only the servers we need.

I set up vmss to boot up another server with the remote agent using auto-scaling, but every time the server fires up, it can create a new/different server name, and creates a new Agent ID. which needs human interaction/approval. Which doesn't really help the hands off approach.

I was thinking of using Availability Sets, where I can have it set up to have say five servers in waiting, and only boot one up, if the auto-scaling says so. I figure I would only have to boot up once to approve the agents, but then they would boot up without any user interaction. I do not see anything through google, etc, to make this happen. Any ideas? Solutions?

Answer (score -1):

> I would only have to boot up once to approve the agents, but then they
>   would boot up without any user interaction.

I guess you want to use Azure create VMs automatically, without user interaction, if I understand it correctly, I think we should use Azure VMSS to achieve that.

In Azure, we can use your image to create VMSS in same availability set, **Azure will scale VMSS instance in or out automatically, without user interaction**.

Azure VMSS use autoscale rule to scale in or scale out, we can according CPU percentage threshold or other metrics to scale VMSS in or out. Like this:

[image]

More information about VMSS, please refer to this official [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-overview).

---

**Update:**

Sorry for my misunderstand.
In your scenario, I think we can create VMs and configure IP addresses as static, and copy the IP address and agent ID to your Bamboo settings.

we can create 5 VMs in the same Vnet, and **use automation runbook to start or shutdown VM.**
[image]

More information about use automation to start or shutdown VM, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management).

Comment: But the thing is with this, is that when the bamboo agents are created on this, they are required to be approved on the master bamboo server. Every single time a server is built. That is the part I am trying to get around. If the server is already pre-built, and just turned on by the same rules as the vmss does for building. It would solve my problem. But I don't see any way of doing this. The example of vmss, even if it 'rebuilds' a server with the same name and ip address, the agent that runs gets a new agent ID, making me required to go in and manually approve it. Making it not be hands off

Comment: only reason downvoting your post is because I said I was already using vmss.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstand, in this scenario, we can't use VMSS to deploy this, because we can't per-defined the Agent ID. Maybe we should use VMs to achieve this, we can create 5 VMs, and use static IP address, then shutdown those VMs, then use automation runbook to start or stop VMs in schedule, I will update my answer, please check it.

Comment: So in your new example are you suggesting to put those workbooks on a schedule? And not on some sort of scaling algorithm?

Comment: @GregP Because in VMSS, we can't per-define the agent ID, so I think we should use schedule to achieve it.